# jquery full calendar: initialize an array from source every time new events are fetched

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, fullcalendar

I want to initialize a global array of events everytime new events are fetched from the database. T explain some more, i want my events in a global array on the client side so that i can filter events without an ajax call. For example, if i have events, and each event has a country associated with it, i have multiple select box where you can select one or more country. I use the clientEvents functions to filter events taht match the criteria but the problem comes when the user starts reducing the filters. Then i need the events that i have already filtered out and for that i dont want to make an ajax call. So my approach is to have a global array of events, and when the user clears the filters, i just simply refectch all the events from that array.

Now the problem is , where to initialize that array?? if i do it in eventAfterRender, it changes in when the filtered events are being rendered, if i do it in viewDisplay, it isnt even initialized, i dont know why, i read somewhere that viewDisplay gets called before the events are rendered if you are using json feed. So i am stuck.... Please any help would be great.

Comment: come on guys ... some one ... i am totally stuck here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function as the feed:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Then you can load the events from wherever you want and combine your array with data from a json source. It is up to your function to decide where to grab the data.

I suppose you will have to call the [refetchEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) method after some external factors like choosing another country is done (your function providing events should take the selection of countries into concideration when generating the events to display).